# AWS media convert generated mpd file doesn't play on dash players with other than Preset configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to stream an mpd file generated by AWS media convert in DASH ISO format. I'm able to play only videos generated using Preset output settings. Also audio settings cannot be enabled while preselecting the output configuration.

Uploaded mp4 file in s3 and using aws media convert created 4 different quality video files and a corresponding mpd file.

While streaming mpd file in dash iso player. It shows error as invalid manifest file while using output settings other than preselect output options. I expect the mpd file should play with specified audio and video quality